# Unable to select the address for inbound new guest appointment flow

Tags: community, visual-workflow, lightning-scheduler

I'm facing some issues to allow the guest user to create an appointment in Experience Cloud. To clarify: I went through the documentation of enabling the flow to a guest user (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_set_up_guest_users.htm&type=5), I did all the configuration in regards to the permissions that a guest user must have in order to create an appointment but when selecting the Service Territory I get the following message:
"No results for that Work Type Group found in that service territory. Try a different address, or expand your search area."

[image]

However, the work type group is associated with the correct work type that contains the resource. So for me, it doesn't seem like an error related to the configuration. Moreover, I hardcoded the variables WorktypeGroupId, Latitude, and Longitude to see if this would "bypass" the rule and allows me to create an appointment, but still facing the same issue.
Also, I reviewed and added test-location.force.com to CSP and CORS. Last but not least, I tried to run the flow using sharing settings mode but still saw the same issue.

The strange thing is that when debugging/running the flow within Salesforce I can see that all the rules are respected and I can proceed with the appointment, the same doesn't happen when I am trying to generate this appointment in an anonymous tab.

Any idea of what could potentially cause this error?

Comment: What is the sharing setting on "Work Type" and "Work Type Group" object? You might want to test by setting external ‘public read/write’

Comment: Following up to see if you have any inputs?

Comment: Thank you Swetha, indeed you were right. The problem was related to the sharing settings of the Work Type Group.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @Youssef Kanso. I've posted it as an answer so it can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that when debugging/running the flow you can proceed with the appointment and as the issue is specific to the guest users,it appears to be an issue with the access.

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_guest_sharing_criteria.htm&type=5),

> Service Resource, Service Territory, Work Type, and Work Type Group require at least one sharing rule each. Without at least one sharing rule per object, unauthenticated users can’t access the records required for the Inbound New Guest Appointment flow.

As confirmed in the comments, adjusting the sharing settings of the Work Type Group fixed the issue.